# flutter: connect Linux development machine with remote Xcode for building and iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter, dart

[Xamarin makes it possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ios-simulator/) to connect to a remote iOS simulator:

> The Remoted iOS Simulator for Windows allows you to test your apps on
>   an iOS simulator displayed in Windows alongside Visual Studio 2019 and
>   Visual Studio 2017.

Does a similar technology exist for flutter?

Specifically, I would like to integrate Android Studio on Linux with a remote Mac hosting Xcode Server.